# Set New Final State After CSS Animation Complete

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have an HTML Element with a CSS Animation applied to it that I want to snap to a different style after the animation finishes

```css
.animatingElement {
   -webkit-animation: myAnimation 0.25s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myAnimation {
  from {
    state1
    }
  to {  
    state2
    }
}

.animatingElementFinal {
   /*desired final/3rd state*/
}
```

Is there any way to, after the animation completes, have it apply a different style than the final state of the animation?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: why don't you simply put your state3 as the final keyframe?

Comment: I did that with a 0% to 99% to a 100% style keyframe deal and even that 99-100% was a little more smooth than I wanted, is there a way to make a smooth animation between 2 keyframes and then snap to the last keyframe?

Comment: try with `99.99%`

Comment: remove forwards and add the state to the element

Comment: Word, that appears to be working a lot better. I didn't realize you could to decimals with keyframes. Thanks!